# Matching filenames in loop

Tags: r

I want to loop through an array and match filenames to particular variables.

I am attempting to do so like this:

```
file.names = c("common", "08f13", "13f08")
for (f in file.names){
  if grep("common", f) {
    a=f
  } else if grep("08f13", f){
    b=f
  } else
    c=f
}
```

and if `common` is in the filename I want to assign it to the variable `a` and if `08` is in the filename assign it to `b` and so on.  Based on the errors I am getting in r I think there is something wrong with the structure of my loop, or I am even using `grep` incorrectly.

My code returns this error:

```
Error: unexpected '}' in "}"
```

Comment: It was supposed to be the full name, that was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
file.names = list.files(path, pattern=".prj")
for (f in file.names){
  if(grepl("common", f))  {
    a=f
  } else if(grepl("08", f)) {
    b=f
  } else {
    c=f
  }
}
```

Mistakes:

1. Round brackets around `if`, `else if` blocks
2. `grep` returns 1 / 0 which are integers and `grepl` returns TRUE / FALSE